# How to set UV map when rendering in Blender Render with nodes?

Tags: uv, node-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to use the node graph in Blender Render to draw a simple plane with a texture on it.  My current setup seems to reading a green pixel from my texture and applying it to the whole surface.  I'd like the texture to follow the UV coordinates that I unwrapped, but can find no place to specify the UV map that I want.

How would I change this to draw my texture on my plane?

[image]

Comment: I think either: SHIFT + "A" INPUT > Texture Coordinates or SHIFT + "A" INPUT > UV Map would work. You would need to select your UV Map withen those Nodes if you have more than one UV Map.

Comment: Oh... and connect one of those Nodes to the Vector Socket of your Texture Node.